# Microsoft Translator Service sample app not working

Tags: microsoft-translator, windows-community-toolkit

When open the sample app from the link provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/services/microsofttranslator), the sample opens as shown below. I then enter the `Translator service key` in the first input box. But when I click on the `Get Languages` button to select a language, the entire sample app disappear. I tried it several times but to no avail. I'm using `Windows-10 Pro 1903`

**Question**: What I may be missing here and how can we make it work?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this seems like a bug in our Sample App? It'd be great if you can [file an issue on our GitHub repo here](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues) for tracking and resolution.

You could also try cloning our repo to build the sample app locally, [see video about setting that up here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jx4_W7fO8Gs), that way you could see the actual exception occurring and provide a bit more detail in the issue (or see what needs to be fixed and submit a PR).

Thanks!